# in protocol with regard to sequence

Tags: python, protocols

How is this implemented at a python level?

I've got an object that pretends to be a dict for the most part (in retrospect I should have just subclassed dict, but I'd rather not refactor the codebase, and I'd also like to know this for future reference), which looks something a bit like

```
class configThinger(object):
    _config = {}
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._config[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._config[key] = value
```

Which works exactly as it's supposed to and behaves correctly when I try to access it's elements as configThingerInstance['whatever']

But a call like

```
t = configThinger()
t.populate() # Internal method that fills it with some useful data
if 'DEBUG' in t:
    doStuff()
```

results in a KeyError being raised because presumably the `in' protocol does a **getitem**() lookup for the key in question. Do I need to raise some other exception to tell in that it's not there?
I'd rather not do something like this.

```
try:
    t['DEBUG']
except KeyError:
    pass
else:
    doStuff()
```

Also, where in the documentation is this?

I was looking around

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

but tragically trying to google for something specific to the word 'in' is folly :(

EDIT 1:

With a stack of trace prints, I can see that the program calls configThingerInstance.**getitem**(0)

however

```
t = {'rawk': 1,
     'rawr': 2,
    }
t[0] # Raises KeyError
'thing' in t # returns False
```

Comment: @Richo, what you're observing is a desperate last-ditch attempt for types that define neither `__contain__` nor `__iter__` (it's trying to see whether, just maybe, they're iterables afraid to speak that name;-).

Comment: I had a hunch that's what it was, which was the point where I started looking for docs, then asking here, rather than fumbling about trying to find some easter egg kludge Guido left laying about ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to overload the in operator?

You can do that by defining the method `__contains__`: [http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**contains**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

Answer (score 1):

For the best support for the `in` operator (containment aka membership checking), implement the `__contains__` special method on your `configThinger` class:

```
class configThinger(object):
    _config = {}
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._config[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self._config[key] = value
    def __contains__(self, key):
        return key in self._config
```

the docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__contains__#object.__contains__) (also explaining other, lesser ways to support the `in` operator).